# Export database record as CSV file

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-workbench

Is there any way to export database records as CSV file from  Mysql Workbench by using command line syntax?

Comment: This is what you need : http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT orderNumber, status, orderDate, requiredDate, comments 
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'Cancelled'
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/cancelled_orders.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

more information here:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

Comment: it works fine. Is it possible run by using batch file.? some sort of automation job.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench comes with a table data export function, which supports csv and json formats. You can start it from the context menu in the schema tree:

[image]

The simple wizard then allows you to select the output data type:

[image]

Similarly, there's the table data import wizard that can read csv and json data.